# In Laravel 3 - need help passing nested data

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I have user's pics in the users table and I want access to these pics based on the invites I have sent. Trying to grab all the user pictures which relate to all the invtites I have sent. I have a model structure like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{

public static $table = 'users';
public static $accessible = array('username', 'email', 'picture', 'password');

public function nests()
{
    return $this->has_many('Nest');
}
```

---

```
class Nest extends Eloquent
{

public static $table = 'nests';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongs_to('User');
}
```

---

```
class Invite extends Eloquent
{

public static $table = 'invite';


public function nest()
{
    return $this->belongs_to('Nest');
}
```

---

Here are my migrations:

```
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table) {
    // auto incremental id (PK)
        $table->increments('id');
    // varchar 32
        $table->string('username', 32);
        $table->string('email', 64);
        $table->string('picture');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('role');
    // boolean
        $table->boolean('true');
    // created_at | updated_at DATETIME
        $table->timestamps();   
    });
}
```

---

```
    {
    Schema::create('nests', function($table) {
    // auto incremental id (PK)
        $table->increments('id');
    // varchar 32
        $table->string('nestname', 128);
        $table->text('info');
        $table->integer('user_id');
    // boolean
        $table->boolean('active');
    // created_at | updated_at DATETIME
        $table->timestamps();   
    });
}
```

---

```
{
    Schema::create('invite', function($table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('mypeeps');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('nest_id');
        $table->string('email', 128);
        $table->timestamps();   
    });
}
```

Here is how I am trying to get the pics but it is not working:

```
    $users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('nests', 'nests.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('invite', 'invite.nest_id', '=', 'nests.id')
    ->where_nest_id($id)
    ->get(array('users.picture', 'users.username'));
```

Comment: 1. You've not actually described the error you're getting... please share what happens when you run this code, and what you expect to happen.  2. You've clearly read some of the docs, but why did you stop before you got to [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#eager)?  You've set up relationships and shared them with us, but decided not to use them... why is this?

Comment: I want to eager load since it is much more efficient. However, from the docs, I am not able to figure out how to do nested joins like this. Fluent is more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm trying to guess what is your problem, but I thinks is that your query is wrong and you fetch only one user, because I tried your code and that is what happened to me.

You said that you want to fetch the pictures of the user based on the invitation that you sent, so the most easy way is join the user table with invite table, but in the code that you put, your query is based on a nested id.

I change your query in order to fetch first the Ids of invitations, based on the id of nest.  Then, I made another query in where the process is join the user table with the ids of invitations.

```
 // fetch the ids of invitation
 $inviteIds = DB::table('invite')
    ->join('nests', 'invite.nest_id', '=', 'nests.id')
    ->where_nest_id($id)
    ->get('invite.id');

 // There must be a better clean solution for this, but it works
 $ids = array();
 foreach($inviteIds as $id){
     $ids[] = $id->id;
 }

 // array of id of invites
 $users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('invite', 'invite.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where_in('invite.id', $ids)
    ->get(array('users.picture', 'users.username'));

 // show the users
 dd($users);
```